# Why my loop doesn't run

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object, for-loop

I am stuck at this challenge in freecodecamp [Profile Lookup](https://www.freecodecamp.com/challenges/profile-lookup) and here is my code, i don't understand why my loop isn't running, it checks only the first element contacts[0], why i doesn't get incremented ?

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){

 for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
    if(contacts[i].firstName===firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
      return contacts[i][prop];
    }
  else if(contacts[i].firstName !== firstName){
      return "No such contact";
    }
    else if (contacts[i].prop!==prop){
      return "No such property";
    }


  }


}
```

Comment: You are returning from the function. Once you hit a `return` statement, the function is done. What did you expect to have happen?

Comment: You return if 1) the first name matches and the object has a given property 2) if the first name does *not* match and 3) if the object's `prop` property is not equal to the `prop` value. Sounds like it almost definitely returns on the first object.

Comment: It also looks like your "if" logic is not going to work. It's always going to return on the first true "if" statement.

Comment: Thanks @MattBurland, you are right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove the else if conditions as it will always return if the first contact in the array does not match the first name.

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop) {
  for (var i = 0; i < contacts.length; i++) {
    if (contacts[i].firstName === firstName) {
      if (contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop))
        return contacts[i][prop];
      else
        return "Contact found but the property " + prop + " does not exist.";
    }
  }
  return "No contact found.";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be something more like this:

```
function lookUpProfile(firstName, prop){

    for(var i=0;i<contacts.length;i++){
      if(contacts[i].firstName===firstName && contacts[i].hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        return contacts[i][prop];
      }
    }

    return "No such contact and property";
}
```

Otherwise you are returning after the first loop no matter what. This way the method will loop through every record and only return the error message if it doesn't match.